# Clueless as to how to proceed and improve my chess neural network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, chess

I am starting to make a neural network that can learn chess. As of current, my training data is roughly 50 million lines long and stored in a CSV file, where each line contains a fen and an outcome. I've made a model and a small function so far. It can play, but not very well.

```
def create_model() -> tf.keras.Model:
    """Create and return a TensorFlow model for evaluating chess positions.

    Returns:
        A TensorFlow model.
    """
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2',  input_shape=(8, 8, 12)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
    
    optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def train() -> None:
    """
    Train the TensorFlow model using the data in the `sample_fen.csv` file. The model is saved to the file `weights.h5` after training.
    """
    # This is only needed for training
    import pandas as pd

    training_data = pd.read_csv(r'neural_net\Players\mtcs_engine\sample_fen.csv', chunksize=100000)
    model = create_model()

    try:
        model.load_weights(r"neural_net\Players\mtcs_engine\weights.h5")
        print("Weights file found. Loading weights.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No weights file found. Training from scratch.")

    try:
        for cycle, chunk in enumerate(training_data):
            games = chunk.values.tolist()
            if cycle <= 11:
                continue
            # Preprocess the data
            positions = []
            outcomes = []

            for game in games:
                position = fen_to_tensor(game[0])
                outcome = game[1]
                
                if outcome == "w":
                    one_hot_outcome = [1, 0]
                elif outcome == "b":
                    one_hot_outcome = [0, 1]
                else:
                    one_hot_outcome = [0, 0] 

                outcomes.append(one_hot_outcome)
                positions.append(position)

            positions = np.array(positions)
            outcomes = np.array(outcomes)

            model.fit(positions, outcomes, epochs=150, batch_size=64)
            print(f"Finished training cycle {cycle}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    model.save_weights(r"neural_net\Players\mtcs_engine\weights.h5")
    print()
    print("Saved weights to disk")
```

but upon learning for around a day its accuracy has increased from 0.5000 to 0.5100 with a loss in the hundreds of thousands. To be honest, I'm not really sure what I'm doing at all. Does anyone have any pointers, be it with the model or anything else? Full code can be found at https://github.com/Iridum-png/warden-chess/blob/master/neural_net/Players/mtcs_engine/mtcs_engine.py

Comment: If anyone needs/wants any more information feel free to ask, but all the relevant code is in the repository

Comment: If I understand correctly your data is a list of positions and whether or not that game ended in a win, loss, or draw. Is this correct?

If that is right, I would think that a neural net trained with this method may be having a hard time extrapolating from positions it has seen to ones it has not. Although I'm not that hot with neural networks.

Comment: Yeah it is that @44stonelions. I tried training it with the scores from stockfish as well, but in my little testing it didn't seem to do too well either. The output is currently the % chance of winning a position for w/b

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think more about what it is you're trying to accomplish. Working in AI is difficult but far from impossible for beginners, but it's important to remember to start small. That is to say, answer these questions in order:

- What is the model's goal?
- How can it best achieve it?
- What do I need to do to handle the model's inputs and outputs to realistically make these predictions?

It looks like all your model is trying to do is determine if a game is a win for white or for black. Is that what you want it to do?

You also need to do quite a bit of research into what each layer in your network is for. In particular: this stretch is highly problematic and will lead to a very confused output due to your use of dropouts (which are good for preventing overfitting but it seems the opposite is the case for you):

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
```

If you want this model to PLAY chess I would suggest having your network do the following:

- Take as input the 8,8 chess board, but also provide it with a move. This way the model can output a probability of the move instead of trying to guess at what to play (which is much more difficult). You can also provide the color to play for additional aid
- Research the monte-carlo search and how alpha-zero implemented it

All in all, making a move prediction from only a board, while possible, is extremely difficult, and would require 2000+ epochs to have a hope of a chance at, and even then, the model would be woefully inept at looking ahead and wouldn't get much above 600 ELO if I had to guess.

Comment: Also, worth noting that we can't see the function you used to create your inputs. If you do something like initialize np arrays with np.empty instead of np.zeros you can run into nan issues that prevent valid training

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The goal is, I suppose, to play chess as well as possible. Since making this post, and from feedback of others, I have swapped to currently essentially doing a regression task against the Stockfish engine eval of a position, but even after ~1000 epochs it does not seem to be playing much better. The input for the board takes a FEN position and converts it into a numpy array - more of a mask of the board and where each piece is, strutted as (8, 8, 12). A 1 if a piece is there, 0 if not. The 12 are for the 6 pieces of 2 different colours.